# How to uncheck all checkboxes on two separate rows in google sheets

Tags: checkbox

I have a spreadsheet that will be used as a check sheet on an ambulance. There are two rows that have check boxes and I want to be able to have a button or a check box and set a trigger to turn these to false. I started using this and it worked the first time I used it but when I created a button and assigned the script it no longer worked.

```
function uncheckAllCheckboxes() {
   var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A2:A45');
   var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('D2:D45');
   range.uncheck();
}
```

I have Checkboxes in cells A2 through A45 and again on D2 though D 34. I thought I had figured it out but I am still learning. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I changed my code to the following: function uncheckAllCheckboxes() {
   var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A2:D35');
  range.uncheck();
} This got everything to uncheck except A39 through A45. I am not sure why those are not being unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason your code is not working is because you have redefined the 'range' variable to the second range. This means the first range is no longer being referenced.

Instead, you should consider defining 'range' as a union of the two ranges by using the 'union()' method, and then uncheck all of the checkboxes within that union range.

Try the following code:

```
function uncheckAllCheckboxes() {
   var range1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A2:A45');
   var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('D2:D45');
   var unionRange = range1.union(range2);
   unionRange.uncheck();
}
```

The above code defines 'range1' and 'range2' as the two seperate ranges of checkboxes, and also defines 'unionRange' as a union of those two ranges using the previously mentioned 'union()' method.
This allows unchecks of all checkboxes, rather it will uncheck them - in the 'unionRange' using the 'uncheck()' method.

Additionally, if this works for you, you can assign the 'uncheckAllCheckBoxes()' function to a button and trigger this.